# Tailwind CSS layout loses background

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Using `h-screen` works until my datepicker comes up which expands the viewport[image]

How do I make the background still fill (once a date box is hovered on it pops up the date picker)? The white space at the bottom of the date picker is the problem. I have a sidebar component for left-hand nav and a main content area.

Main content code:

```
.main-content {
        @apply p-6 h-screen w-screen flex flex-col bg-slate-800 shadow-lg m-0 text-white;
    }
```

Sidebar css:

```
.sidebar {
        @apply h-screen w-20 flex flex-col bg-gray-900 shadow-lg m-0 px-3;
    }
```

Datepicker code:

```
<div className="flex datepicker group-hover:scale-100 z-10">
        <div className="grid grid-col-7 w-64 bg-gray-700 p-2 rounded-lg shadow-xl">
            <div className="sub-text text-center">
                {DateValue.monthLong} {DateValue.year}
                <span
                    className="m-2 px-2 py-1 bg-gray-700 rounded-3xl hover:bg-gray-900 cursor-pointer"
                    onClick={(e) => changeMonth(e, false)}
                >
                    &#60;
                </span>
                <span
                    className="px-2 py-1 bg-gray-700 rounded-3xl hover:bg-gray-900 cursor-pointer"
                    onClick={(e) => changeMonth(e, true)}
                >
                    &#62;
                </span>
            </div>
            <hr className="mb-2" />
            <div className="grid grid-cols-7 pb-2">
                <div className="text-center">Su</div>
                <div className="text-center">Mo</div>
                <div className="text-center">Tu</div>
                <div className="text-center">We</div>
                <div className="text-center">Th</div>
                <div className="text-center">Fr</div>
                <div className="text-center">Sa</div>
            </div>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-7">{daysAsInput()}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS (Tailwind Apply)

```
.datepicker {
@apply absolute transition-all duration-100 scale-0;
```

}

.datepicker-day {
@apply m-1 bg-gray-700 rounded-lg shadow-lg
cursor-pointer items-center justify-center
p-1 text-sky-400 hover:bg-gray-900;
}

It scales to `100` when the input is hovered over.

Layout code:

```
<div className="flex">
    <Sidebar />
    <div className="main-content min-h-screen">{children}</div>
</div>
```

daysAsInput code:

```
const daysAsInput = () => {
    // loop through the days in the month but start at the first day of the week
    const inputs = [];
    for (
        let i = firstDayOfMonthAligned.day;
        i <= firstDayOfMonthAligned.daysInMonth;
        i++
    ) {
        // create input that's grayed out if it's not in the current month
        inputs.push(
            <input
                key={'previousMonth ' + i}
                className="datepicker-day disabled:text-gray-400"
                type="button"
                value={i}
                disabled={true}
                onClick={dateChanged}
            />
        );
    }
    for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
        inputs.push(
            <input
                className="datepicker-day"
                key={i}
                type="button"
                name="day {i}"
                value={i}
                onClick={dateChanged}
            />
        );
    }
    return inputs;
};
```

Comment: Try to use `min-h-full` instead of `h-screen`.

Comment: technically your "layout" it's not the layout. it's just a div so i can't see the whole picture. Nevertheless what i end up doin is adding **h-screen flex flex-col** to the `body` and **flex-grow** to my `main` tag which contains all my content except the `header` and the `footer`... `header` and `footer` are out of the `main` tag

Comment: Using next.js, accessing body element sucks. Was attempting to not have to do work-arounds

Comment: The problem is caused by the fact that you position the datepicker `absolute`. From the [docs] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position): “The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout”. You must take another approach, probably with z-index or javascript.

Comment: @Gabe That seems to be exactly what's happening. Now, I just have to get everything aligned correctly without absolute (as removing it jacks up everything). If you want to submit that as an answer, the bounty is yours. I appreciate you.

Comment: @BRogers That’s very kind :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that you position the datepicker `absolute`.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is
> created for the element in the page layout.

You must take another approach, probably with z-index or javascript.

Comment: I now have some weird spacing issues that I'll probably resolve with z-index. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by weird spacing issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it to min-h-screen . That should do the magic

Comment: No go, tried adding it to both the sidebar and the main-content.

Comment: How many pixels is the datepicker height? it seems odd it is taller than the whole screen height

Comment: After inspecting it looks to be 309 pixels. Added additional code in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, we need to adjust the height styling of main-content class.

We can add "min-h-full" to the main-content class,

```css
.main-content {
        @apply p-6 h-screen w-screen flex flex-col bg-slate-800 shadow-lg m-0 text-white min-h-full;
    }
```

This tailwind class will adjust the height of main-content to 100%. And the white background, have no room anymore.

Here was the [reference of min-height](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-height)

Thank you

Comment: Tried that out and it didn't work. Thanks for the thought though. I did several different variations as well.